# CSS specification table

Tags: css

where can I find the CSS specification table as illustrating what properties support what version of CSS?

could any one point me to the right source of information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site has a great overview with all css properties and from which browser-/css- version the property was supported.

http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/css/supportkey/syntax.htm

Answer (score 4):

[Property Index](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/#properties) definitions in w3c

Answer (score 3):

http://caniuse.com/ contains a wide variety of compatibility tables that will let you know precisely which browsers support which features.

Answer (score 1):

Related: CSS properties supported by various email clients, courtesy of Campaign Monitor:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Email clients covered:

- MS Outlook 2007 / 2010
- MS Outlook 2000 / 2003
- Apple iOS (iPhone, iPad)
- Windows Live Hotmail
- Apple Mail 4
- Google GMail
- Google GMail on Android

...amongst others.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org)

Answer (score 0):

Sitepoint has brilliant [CSS Reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css) that tells you about the various properties, selectors and "at-rules" as well as browser compatibility, including a break down of exactly what problems each browser has.